# Why are floats denormalized to deal with underflow instead of overflow?

Tags: floating-point, binary, ieee-754

When denormalized couldn't the exponent on, let's say single point precision floats, represent 128 (instead of -126) and the mantissa (with an added 1 at the end) just be multiplied by 2^{128}? This way the biggest number would be (2^23-1)*2^128 instead of 2^{128}-1. Granted now we have lost the possibility to represent numbers smaller than 2^{-126} but those would in nearly all cases be 0 anyway...

Comment: The largest finite value is (1−2^−23)•2^127, not 2^128−1. The scheme you propose would make the largest value (1−2^-23)•2^128, not (2^23-1)•2^128.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170944/understanding-the-usefulness-of-denormalized-floating-point-numbers). In short, subnormal numbers are useful not because they are small but because of their arithmetic properties: They eliminate some oddities that would occur at the bottom of the floating-point range (regardless of where you set that bottom) by stopping the floating. Without subnormals, some representable values would have bits whose individual values could not be represented as numbers on their own.